# Cannot ssh to server as I install poste.io on OVH dedicated server

Tags: docker, ssh, mail-server

I'm a beginner in `docker` and `poste.io`.
I want to install `poste.io` with `docker` on my server .
`Poste.io` & `Docker` installed without problem and running fine but when my connection dropped and I try ssh to server again **my connection will be timed out and cannot connect to server** .

**docker command :**

```
docker run \
    -p 25:25 \
    -p 9925:80 \
    -p 110:110 \
    -p 143:143 \
    -p 9926:443 \
    -p 465:465 \
    -p 587:587 \
    -p 993:993 \
    -p 995:995 \
    -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
    -v /root/mailserver/data:/data \
    --name "mailserver" \
    -t analogic/poste.io
```

Comment: we cannot help you. You have to do it on your own...

Comment: thank you Jonas ...

Comment: Yeah im sorry, you may have a look at SuperUser, they are more experienced in Stuff like that

Comment: Try to ping your server, see if it's still online. Also try to open virtual console if OVH provides it to see if anything weird is going on. I don't think Docker and SSH problems are really connected in any way except if resources are too low.

Comment: I solved problem but not completely.
As I changed ssh server port to another(not 22) , I can connect to server via ssh.
(I don't know why docker run on server ssh on port 22 not worked.)